# Absolute value of Jacobi sum $J(\chi,\psi)$ for Dirichlet characters

Tags: characters, jacobi-sums

We know that a character $\chi$ on a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, $q$ being a power of a prime, is a group homomomorphism $\chi:\mathbb{F}_q^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. For characters $\chi,\psi$ on $\mathbb{F}_q$, the Jacobi sum $J(\chi,\psi)$ has absolute value $\sqrt{q}$. My question  is, is there any corresponding result for  Dirichlet characters $\chi$ modulo $n$ (primitive or non-primitive) where $n$ is a positive integer or in the special case where $n$ is a power of a prime?

Comment: anything unclear?

Comment: No but I was wondering why the modulus result holds if the characters are primitive and maybe not otherwise?

Comment: Ok I got your point, sorry for the dumb mistake. Note that with $n=ab,\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\chi=\chi_a\chi_b,\psi=\psi_a\psi_b$ with $\chi_a$ a Dirichlet character modulo $a$  and $J(\chi,\psi) = J(\chi_a,\psi_a)J(\chi_b,\psi_b)$ so you get the result $|J(\chi,\psi)|=\sqrt{n}$ if $n$ is squarefree and $\chi,\psi,\chi\psi$ are primitive.

Answer (score 1):

- First note that there is some kind of multiplicativity:
  write $\chi=\prod_{p^k\| n} \chi_{p^k}$ where $\chi_{p^k}$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $\chi_{p^k}$, you'll get that $$J(\chi,\psi)=\prod_{p^k\| n} J(\chi_{p^k},\psi_{p^k})$$
- Then assume that $\chi,\psi,\chi\psi$ are primitive. It is well-known that $$\chi(a)= \frac{G(\chi)}{n}\sum_{k\bmod n} e^{-2i\pi ak/n}\overline{\chi}(k), \qquad |G(\chi)|^2=n$$
  from which $$J(\chi,\psi)= \sum_{a\bmod n} \chi(a)\psi(1-a)$$
  $$=\frac{G(\chi)G(\psi)}{n^2}\sum_{a\bmod n}\sum_{k\bmod n}\sum_{l\bmod n} e^{-2i\pi (ak+(1-a)l)/n}\overline{\chi}(k)\overline{\psi}(l)
  $$
  $$ = \frac{G(\chi)G(\psi)}{n^2}\sum_{k\bmod n}n e^{-2i\pi k/n}\overline{\chi}(k)\overline{\psi}(k)=\frac{G(\chi)G(\psi)}{n}\overline{G(\chi\psi)}=\frac{G(\chi)G(\psi)}{G(\chi\psi)}$$
  $$|J(\chi,\psi)|=\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: In the last step of the summation, is it always true that a-c is a unit in Z_n if a is?

Comment: No, right, I need to assume that $\chi\psi$ is non-trivial for the sum over $c$ with $a=0$ to vanish. If $\chi\psi$ is trivial then it is $G(\chi \psi) J(\chi,\psi)=G(\chi)G(\psi)-\psi(-1)\phi(n)$

Comment: Is it only enough to consider only for a=0? What about other a in Z_n which are not relatively coprime to n?

Comment: I changed my answer. Of course the solution was to use the main result for primitive Dirichlet characters, namely the expression for their discrete Fourier transform.